# Is there a way to fill missing values in multiple columns sharing part of their name with values from another column?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, fillna

I am trying to fill NaN in multiple columns (too many for the solution to be hardcoded) that share part of their name with values from another column in the same pandas dataframe.

I know that I can fill multiple columns using a constant value and also that I can fill a single column using another from the same dataframe. It's the combination of these two that is not working for me.

For example, consider the data frame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Val': [1.2,5.4,3.1,4], 'Col - 1': [None,5,1,None], 'Col - 2': [None,None,6,None]})
print(df)

   Val  Col - 1  Col - 2
0  1.2      NaN      NaN
1  5.4      5.0      NaN
2  3.1      1.0      6.0
3  4.0      NaN      NaN
```

Filling multiple columns with a constant value works:

```py
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Col')] = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Col')].fillna(value=15)
print(df)

   Val  Col - 1  Col - 2
0  1.2     15.0     15.0
1  5.4      5.0     15.0
2  3.1      1.0      6.0
3  4.0     15.0     15.0
```

Filling a single column with values from another column also works:

```py
df['Col - 2'] = df['Col - 2'].fillna(value=df['Val'])
print(df)

   Val  Col - 1  Col - 2
0  1.2      NaN      1.2
1  5.4      5.0      5.4
2  3.1      1.0      6.0
3  4.0      NaN      4.0
```

What doesn't work is a combination of the two:

```py
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Col')] = df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Col')].fillna(value=df['Val'])
```

The above does nothing and returns the original dataframe. What I am expecting is this:

```py
   Val  Col - 1  Col - 2
0  1.2      1.2      1.2
1  5.4      5.0      5.4
2  3.1      1.0      6.0
3  4.0      4.0      4.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should adding `apply` `lambda` , since dataframe `fillna` will also check the `columns` name , you fill it by the `pd.Series`, which do not match the `columns` , so will make the fillna failed

```
df.loc[:,df.columns.str.contains('Col')].apply(lambda x : x.fillna(value=df['Val']))
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`df.filter()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html) here:

```
m=df.filter(like='Col')
df[m.columns]=m.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(df.Val))
print(df)
```

---

```
   Val  Col - 1  Col - 2
0  1.2      1.2      1.2
1  5.4      5.0      5.4
2  3.1      1.0      6.0
3  4.0      4.0      4.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way around the problem with `np.where`:

```
cols = [col for col in df.columns if 'Col' in col]
df[cols] = np.where(df[cols].isna(), df.Val.values[:,None], df[cols])
```

Output:

```
      Val    Col - 1    Col - 2
--  -----  ---------  ---------
 0    1.2        1.2        1.2
 1    5.4        5          5.4
 2    3.1        1          6
 3    4          4          4
```